# Compute how much overlap is needed

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry, splitting-field

Given an arrays of length 40 i want to extract 37 equal sized subarrays. 
Since 40 is not dividable by 37, are the subarrays allowed to be overlapping.. but how do i compute the overlap?

I thought that i could compute the overlap using the modulus operator - such that 40%37 = 3.

Problem is that when i extract sub arrays of length 3, I get in total 38 subarrays and not 37... what is wrong here?

Am i computing the overlap incorrectly?.. seems so

If so? how else can I compute the nessesary stride and the window size of a window moving along the length of the array?

Comment: I have one array of length 40 that i want to split in 37 equal sized sub arrays...  I am not sure i understand your comment above @Winther

Comment: It depends on how you split up your arrays. For example if you do it in a regular way as $[1,2,3]$, $[2,3,4]$, ..., $[38,39,40]$ then you end up with $38$ subarrays. However if you do it as $[1,2,3]$ $[3,4,5]$, $[4,5,6]$, ... $[38,39,40]$ then it's $37$.

Comment: ahh!.. that might clear some stuff..

Comment: Is it even possible to compute the size of the sub array given the number of subarrays?